# Intellij Dependency Issue - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have started using IntelliJ for my projects recently. I was trying to develop a simple maven project and got stuck into issue. I was trying to play around with kakfa-clients. Here is my dependencies

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

I tried doing maven clean and install. I see the following error after I execute the code.

```
C:\KB\SDA>java -cp target/SDA-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar org.example.code.Demo
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/Producer
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Producer
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 7 more
```

However I could see the kafka-clients:2.5.0 is available in the External Libraries folder

I would like to know what could have gone wrong. Any hint would definitely help.

Java version 8
IntellJ 2020.1

Comment: Does [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30394898/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-with-intellij-and-maven) helps?

Comment: Any specific reason for using the command line to run the code?

Comment: To make it work in command line, you need to use shaded plugin as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56407760/2987755

Answer (score 0):

`Kafka-Client` itself is dependent on other dependencies. Have a look here https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka-clients/2.5.0

Give a shot by including other jars in the classpath.

```
java -cp target/*.jar:. org.example.code.Demo
```